# netcoreapp3.1 appears to reference C# 7.3 and not 8 as documented

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-8.0, netcoreapp3.0, netcoreapp3.1

I've updated an existing asp.net mvc app from netcoreapp3.0 to netcoreapp3.1, along with all referenced packages.  The project settings have the target framework and my PC has the SDK installed

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
```

I have an error in a place where I use the C# [coaslescing assignment feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#null-coalescing-assignment) `??=`  This was working without issue before updating. @SebastianHofmann has kindly confirmed other C#8 features do not work either.

```
Error   CS8370  Feature 'coalescing assignment' is not available in C# 7.3.
 Please use language version 8.0 or greater.
```

[According to MSFT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version) netcoreapp3.1 should be using C#8 and indeed must
[image]

The advance project settings I just saw has been disabled within Visual Studio 2019 (16.3.10)
[image]

I can toggle back to 3.0 and it compiles again

Comment: Visual Studio 2019 is required for C# 8.0

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2019

Comment: updated the question for clarity

Comment: _"I have just one error in a place where I use the C# coaslescing assignment feature `??=`"_ - what is the code and what is the error? Also, what is the specific version number of Visual Studio you are running?

Comment: Isn't ```??=``` a proposed, not yet implemented feature?

Comment: @CodeCaster updatd answer with both

Comment: @SebastianHofmann it's official going by https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#null-coalescing-assignment

Comment: The C# 8 spec proposal states the opposite: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/null-coalescing-assignment

Comment: Oh, I was wrong. I just have tested it in a new .NET Core 3.0 application where it seems to work.

Comment: thanks @SebastianHofmann it worked for me too in 3.0 but not in 3.1. Have you a 3.1 project you can trial in?  I'm going to spin up an empty project to test.

Comment: I'm getting the same error when setting the version to .NET Core 3.1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203593/discussion-between-dove-and-sebastian-hofmann).

Comment: I've added ??= to an existing Core 3 project and had no errors, then updated VS with latest patch (V 4.7.03062) to get 3.1, then upgraded the project to 3.1 also with no error. the only way I could get your error was down grading the project to 2.1. Is it worth running a repair / update on your VS.

Comment: @dove there's no issue with C# 8. I'm using the previews for 3.1 since they came out. They both work. What does the `LangVersion` element in your `csproj` contain?

Comment: `has been disabled within Visual Studio 2019` and the link explains why. You can override the selection with the `LangVersion` element

Comment: @DavidHinchliffe spot on.  I hadn't seen the new release of Visual Studio, should have thunk of that.  My question does raise a bug only if you don't update.  Answer and I'll accept as you have it right.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have no LangVersion specified, update to 16.4 sorted.  Thanks for tip though

Comment: @dove what does `dotnet --list-sdks` show? There was a bug in the first preview that *removed* 3.0 when VS installed the 3.1 SDK. If you installed the 3.1 SDK yourself there was no problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've added ??= to an existing Core 3 project and had no errors, then updated VS with latest patch (V 4.7.03062) to get 3.1, then upgraded the project to 3.1 also with no error. the only way I could get your error was down grading the project to 2.1. Is it worth running a repair / update on your VS.